# Removing a file when `rm` says it doesn't exist, but it does

Tags: command-line, files, delete

I'm trying to delete a folder my music collection folder. With the command

```
ls -al /mnt/media/Music/
```

I can see the folder - only it has a `?` at the end of the name, so it looks like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 reuben reuben    0 Mar  3 15:24 Twin Shadow - Eclipse (2015) [FLAC]?
```

but when I try to delete it with this command:

```
rmdir /mnt/media/Music/Twin\ Shadow\ -\ Eclipse\ \(2015\)\ [FLAC]\?/
```

Then I get this:

```
rm: cannot remove '/mnt/media/Music/Twin Shadow - Eclipse (2015) [FLAC]?/': No such file or directory
```

I'm confused; what am I missing? I hope it's not something really obvious!

Comment: If you want to use escaping, you will also need to backslash-escape the parentheses and brackets, I think i.e. `/mnt/media/Music/Twin\ Shadow\ -\ Eclipse\ \(2015\)\ \[FLAC\]?/` (or  - simpler - enclose the whole thing in quotes) - if in doubt, type `rmdir /mnt/media/Music/Twin` and then hit the TAB key to autocomplete

Comment: If you submit your solution as an answer i'll check it off for you as the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easiest way to handle filenames like this in the terminal is to make use of the shell's tab completion feature: type enough of the name to be unambiguous e.g.

```
rmdir /mnt/media/Music/Twin\ Shad
```

and then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>

The second easiest way - at least if the name doesn't itself contain quotes - is to quote the whole thing e.g.

```
rmdir '/mnt/media/Twin Shadow - Eclipse (2015) [FLAC]?'
```

(double quotes should also work in this context).

If you **really** need to use backslash escapes, then both parentheses and square brackets are shell metacharacters and must also be escaped i.e.

```
rmdir /mnt/media/Music/Twin\ Shadow\ -\ Eclipse\ \(2015\)\ \[FLAC\]\?/
```

(the `-` doesn't need to be escaped - although it doesn't hurt to do so).